# UIScrollView Subview placement issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

In Interface Builder :

I am not using Autolayout.

I place my `UIScrollView` and then drag in other elements into the `UIScrollView`

When I run my app in the simulator, the subviews of the `UIScrollView` are positioned in the center of the `UIView` instead of where I placed them at.

One item is a `UITextField` and if I dismiss the keyboard, the view repositions itself to how I set it up in Interface Builder.

How can I fix the initial issue of all items being placed in the center of the `UIView`?

Edit:

If I `NSLog` the x and y of my `UITextField`, it shows the correct values of where I set it in Interface Builder, but when the view first appears, the text field is pushed down below that location.

In this case, the x is 20 and the y is 108

Solution:

I did have to check on the autosizing, but I also added the code below and it fixed my issue:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

Comment: No details here... no screenshot do go with an unclear description of what's happening.  No comment on whether or not auto-layout is being used, etc.

Comment: screenshot will help us a lot... To **downvoters**, what is the problem for downvote?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this may help you..

Please try to check the Autosizing of every component in the uiscrollview. The issue may also occur because of the wrong Autosizing of components.

I face the similar issue and got fixed once I correct the Autosizing of every component.